# Clean preprocessor conditionals from fortran code

Tags: compilation, fortran, preprocessor-directive

I work with a very long Fortran code full of preprocessor (#if) conditionals, Is there any way to compile it and get a source file only with the fraction of the code where conditions are satisfied?

Comment: Why don't you just run the preprocessor over it?

Comment: *Why* do you want to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As mentioned by chw21, you can run the preprocessor directly. Either the `cpp` (with the right flags) or the `fpp` command, depending on your compiler.

Because you can be unsure about the right flags, you can also let the compiler do that for you. In GCC (gfortran) it is the `-E` flag, which will force the compiler to stop after preprocessing. You must redirect standard output to a file because the preprocessed code is returned to standard output.

Comment: Thanks you both, Vladimir and chw21. 
`fpp -P src.F src_clean.F`
did the job.

Comment: If you are happy with @VladimirF 's answer, please accept it.